# R: Appending values from row values specified by other row values to a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns - a group number and a name:

```
Group    Name
1        A
4        B
2        C
3        D
4        E
```

I now want to make a list containing all the names that have groups in common.

I have tried with this for loop:

```
myfun <- function(x,g1,g2,g3,g4){
    for (j in 1:nrow(x)){
        if (x[1,j] == 1){
            list(g1, list(c=x[2,j]))
        } else if (x[1,j] == 2){
            list(g2, list(c=x[2,j]))
        } else if (x[1,j] == 3){
            list(g3, list(c=x[2,j]))
        } else if (x[1,j] == 4){
            list(g4, list(c=x[2,j]))
        }               
    } 

}
```

where g1, g2, g3 and g4 are empty lists.
I get this error `Error in if (x[1, i] == 1) { : argument is of length zero`.
Do I have the right approach?

Edit: 
How can I search and extract the level by a value in the list (lets say i want the group with the name B in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code (avoiding all the loops) by using an `apply` function (`dat` is the data)

```
res <- lapply(unique(dat$Group), function(g) unique(dat[dat$Group==g, "Name"]))
names(res) <- unique(dat$Group)
res[["4"]]
# [1] B E
# Levels: A B C D E
```

This creates a list where the indices of the list correspond to `unique(dat$Group)` and each element contains the unique "Name"s in that group.

Another solution, using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
res <- dlply(dat, .(Group), function(x) unique(x$Name))
res[["4"]]
# [1] B E
# Levels: A B C D E

## If you want to extract all the groups with a "B" Name
inds <- unlist(lapply(res, function(x) "B" %in% x))
inds
#     1     2     3     4 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 

## and to extract that Group
names(inds)[inds]
# [1] "4"
```